# find base address of current procrss in kernel space

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, dump, portable-executable

hi i will dump the other process in kernel driver

and use KeStackAttachProcess  to  change driver current context

after user-mode address changed how can find base address of current process
i need base address for cast it to PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER( and parse it to find sections) 
can use PEB?

any other solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a special API function for that:

```
NTKERNELAPI
PVOID
PsGetProcessSectionBaseAddress(
    __in PEPROCESS Process
    );
```

And you can use SectionBaseAddress field in the EPROCESS structure:

```
+0x128 SectionBaseAddress : 0x00400000 Void
```

It may vary in different OS versions.

Comment: i cant find PsGetProcessSectionBaseAddress in WDK , is it undoc?and use it is fine ?

Comment: Yes, it is undoc. Just check whether this function exists on OS versions you want to support. It exists on my w2k3 and w7 machines but I am not sure about earlier systems.